# I cannot call the value of JQuery generated cookie in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, cookies

I have created a cookie that saves the last altered state of a checkbox.  The cookie works, I have proven that by passing the value of said cookie in an  alert box.  the cookie also saves the state of the checkbox on the site.  I need to pass the value of that cookie, or the current checkbox value to thee controller so I can alter the JQuery Datatable accordingly.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my View Script:

```
    $(function () {

        var oTable = $('#myIssuesTable').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "bJQueryUI": true,

            "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("GetIssuesViaAjax", "Exchange")'

        });

        $('#activeOnly').click(function () {

            var activeStatus = $('#activeOnly:checked').val() ?true:false;

            $.cookie("showActiveIssues", activeStatus, { expires: 365 }, { path: '/' });

            alert($.cookie("showActiveIssues"))        
            //if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
            //    alert("ON");
            //else
            //    alert("OFF");
            @*$.post("@Url.Action("GetIssuesViaAjax", "Exchange")", { test: activeStatus });*@
            @*$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetIssuesViaAjax", "Exchange")',
                type: 'POST',
                //dataType: "json",
                //contentType: 'application/json',
                //traditional: true,
                data: {test:"Testarooskie"}*@
        });
            oTable.fnReloadAjax('@Url.Action("GetIssuesViaAjax", "Exchange")');
        });

        $('#activeOnly').ready(function ()
        {
            //alert($.cookie("showActiveIssues"))
            var cbCookie = $.cookie("showActiveIssues")
            if (cbCookie == 1)
            {
                //alert("working correctly")
                $('#activeOnly').prop('checked', true)
            }
            else {
                //alert("working incorrectly")
                $('#activeOnly').prop('checked', false)
            }
        });

    });
</script>

            @Html.CheckBox("activeOnly")
            @Html.Label("Active Only")</>
```

And my Controller:

```
public class ExchangeController : MultiBase
{
    ITExchangeReposity hufDalRepository = new ITExchangeReposity();
    SecurityReposity hufDalSecurityRepository = new SecurityReposity();

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetIssuesViaAjax(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {


        //HttpCookie test = Request.Cookies["showActiveIssues"];
        //Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["showActiveIssues"]);

        bool cbValue = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Cookies["showActiveIssues"]);//returns only default value of "false"

        //string cbValue = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["showActiveIssues"]);//returns an empty value ("").




        var issues = hufDalRepository.FindAllIssues(2 , cbValue);
        var result = from c in issues

        select new[] { c.IDTSSubmitIssue.ToString(), c.Subject, c.IDUser.ToString(), c.ReviewedBy, c.StatusDescription, c.DateSubmitted.ToShortDateString() };

            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = issues.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = issues.Count(),
                aaData = result
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: have u checked in fiddler or firebug to make sure cookie value is travelling with the request?

Comment: I have not, I am thinking at this point that i should try and use a $.ajax call to post the value directly into the controller

Comment: That makes more sense if that value is used only in one or two actionresults.

Comment: I cannot post the checkbox value to the controller because it is being used to populate a jQuery datatable.  I want to modify the population of that table with the checkbox.  I need to access the cookie value, (which is showing the accurate value in firebug lite), directly but Request.cookies["showActiveIssues"] returns a null value.

Comment: Could the type of cookie generated by the jQuery cookie plugin affect how to access it in the controller?